# How to make fill-region/paragraph identify a paragraph prefix?

Tags: fill-paragraph

Let's say I have the following buffer.

```
1. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

Hitting `M-q` here while in `text-mode` leads to the following.

```
1. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

On the other hand, if I activate `markdown-mode`, I get the following
(Markdown is just an example, you see similar behavior in various modes).

```
1. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
   ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

---

**How do I configure text-mode to do that?**

I imagine this can be achieved by writting a special [`fill-paragraph-function`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/fill-paragraph-function), but this variable is just set to `nil` in `markdown-mode`, so there's probably an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sean's gist pointed me in the right direction, and here's the snippet that solved it.

```
(defun my-adaptive-fill-function ()
  "Return prefix for filling paragraph or nil if not determined."
  (cond
   ;; List item inside blockquote
   ((looking-at "^[ \t]*>[ \t]*\\([0-9]+\\.\\|[*+-]\\)[ \t]+")
    (replace-regexp-in-string
     "[0-9\\.*+-]" " " (match-string-no-properties 0)))
   ;; Blockquote
   ((looking-at "^[ \t]*>[ \t]*")
    (match-string-no-properties 0))
   ;; List items
   ((looking-at "^\\([ \t]*\\)\\([0-9]+\\.\\|[\\*\\+-]\\)\\([ \t]+\\)")
    (match-string-no-properties 0))
   ;; No match
   (t nil)))

;; Paragraph filling in text-mode.
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (set (make-local-variable 'paragraph-start)
         "\f\\|[ \t]*$\\|[ \t]*[*+-] \\|[ \t]*[0-9]+\\.[ \t]\\|[ \t]*: ")
    (set (make-local-variable 'paragraph-separate)
         "\\(?:[ \t\f]*\\|.*  \\)$")
    (set (make-local-variable 'adaptive-fill-first-line-regexp)
         "\\`[ \t]*>[ \t]*?\\'")
    (set (make-local-variable 'adaptive-fill-function)
         'my-adaptive-fill-function)))
```

Comment: If I have have empty line as bullet like only start `*`, when I do `M-q` it is removes. Is it possible to prevent to delete empty lines that only have `*`?

Comment: Instead of `*` could I also accomplish this approach for `* @param` as a different pattern ?

Answer (score 6):

I've been a happy user of filladapt-mode for a long time, which handles this sort of thing really nicely. For info, see

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FillAdapt

From that page:

> Filladapt by KyleJones enhances Emacs’ fill functions by guessing a
>   fill prefix, such as a comment sequence in program code, and handling
>   bullet points like “1.” or “*”.

For example, it could turn this

```
* Pretend I'm a really super long line.
* And the window's narrow.
```

into

```
* Pretend I'm a really super
  long line.
* And the window's narrow.
```

Comment: Ok, edited to address that.

Comment: to enable this mode in conjunction w/ another mode, add something like `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-filladapt-mode)` to your config file (this info isn't directly available on the linked wiki page).

Comment: Works beautifully to make `fill-paragraph` behave properly within blockquotes in `markdown-mode`.

Comment: 2 years has passed since the answer.  Download link http://www.wonderworks.com/download/filladapt.el is no longer available.

Comment: The link works for me right now. Maybe there was a temporary problem with the site.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> (fill-paragraph &optional JUSTIFY REGION)
>
> [...]
>
> If `fill-paragraph-function' is non-nil, we call it (passing our
> argument to it), and if it returns non-nil, we simply return its value.
>
> If `fill-paragraph-function' is nil, return the `fill-prefix' used for filling.
>
> [...]
> ```

`markdown-mode` presumably sets `fill-paragraph-function` to `nil` so that the function uses `fill-prefix` to do the filling.

```lisp
(let ((fill-prefix (make-string (length "1. ") ? ))
  (fill-paragraph))
```

Full example:

```lisp
(let* ((num 15)
       (numstr (format "%d. " num))
       (fill-prefix (make-string (length numstr) ? )))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (loop for i from 1 to 15 do
          (insert (format "lorem ipsum (%d) doler sit amet " i)))
    (beginning-of-line)
    (insert numstr)
    (fill-paragraph)
    (buffer-string)))

;; =>

"\
15. lorem ipsum (1) doler sit amet lorem ipsum (2) doler sit amet
    lorem ipsum (3) doler sit amet lorem ipsum (4) doler sit amet
    lorem ipsum (5) doler sit amet lorem ipsum (6) doler sit amet
    lorem ipsum (7) doler sit amet lorem ipsum (8) doler sit amet
    lorem ipsum (9) doler sit amet lorem ipsum (10) doler sit amet
    lorem ipsum (11) doler sit amet lorem ipsum (12) doler sit amet
    lorem ipsum (13) doler sit amet lorem ipsum (14) doler sit amet
    lorem ipsum (15) doler sit amet "
```

Comment: _"markdown-mode presumably sets fill-paragraph-function to nil so that the function uses fill-prefix to do the filling."_ That can't be the whole story. When I hit `M-q`, `fill-paragraph` is invoked directly (there's no let-bind around it). While it's possible that `fill-prefix` is ultimately used for this purpose, there has to be some configuration variable that allows it to be auto-detected.

Comment: @Malabarba Looks like `markdown-mode` actually does this via paragraph definitions: https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/88759fd9f8368adbf663

Comment: Yes, that looks more like it.